# what kind (brand) of LCD display is this? it has no pins

Tags: lcd

I just gutted working new kitchen scale, and I have never seen a LCD display like this before. There are no pins just a black strip that goes on to the PCB.
What brand of LCD is this?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Is there a brand written on your PCB? Then that is your brand. This type of LCD is never sold by itself.

Comment: @NatsuKage Well, actually you can buy this type of LCD, for example at surplus sales. I just found a Philips LCD with much more segments, though. How to connect it is another issue. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

The LCD is not what is special. The special part is the black elastomeric connector. They are sometimes used with LCDs, since most of the connections are very low current, a high-quality connection is not necessary.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastomeric_connector

Answer (score 2):

The LCD has the conductive tracks which are not much difficult to see with naked eyes. Try to flick it against the light.

The black connector are called **zebra** **connectors**. Really cheap and you need some pressure alone to mate the LCD with the zebra connector.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastomeric_connector for reference[image]